# How to apply a single fully connected layer to each point in an image

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to set up a non-conventional neural network using keras, and am having trouble efficiently setting this up.

The first few layers are standard convolutional layers, and the output of these have d channels, which each have image shapes of n x n.

What I want to do is use a single dense layer to map this d x n x n tensor onto a single image of size n x n. I want to define a single dense layer, with input size d, and output size 1, and apply this function to each "pixel" on the input (with the inputs taken depthwise across channels).

So far, I have not found a efficient solution to this. I have tried first defining a fully connected layer, then looping over each "pixel" in the input, however this takes many hours to initialize the model, and I am worried that it will slow down backprop, as the computations are likely not properly parallelized.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a 1x1 convolution with output depth 1. You can implement it just as you implement the rest of the convolution layers. You might want to apply `tf.squeeze` afterwards to remove the depth, which should have size 1.

Comment: Hi, I don't think that this is quite what I want, and perhaps I left out an important factor out of my previous question. This may work if I am trying to map the d x n x n image to a 1 x n x n image, but in actuality I want to do this in 2 steps, i.e. first map it to a d/2 x n x n image, then this to a 1 x n x n image. If I use a 3D convolution with dimension d x 1 x 1, I will get a 1 x n x n image, but I would have to apply separate convolutional filters for each depwise dimension that I would want in the intermediate step. Does this make sense?

Comment: OK, edit that into the question please. Wouldn't that just be two convs with filters `1 x 1 x d x d/2` and `1 x 1 x d x 1`? If the weights are shared between these two filters, how?